# Credentials prompt for access to Azure management APIs

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I've been using the Azure fluent management APIs (https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) with some success in .NET Core.

However, I want to prompt the user to enter some credentials for a Microsoft account.  Those credentials would have access to one or more Azure tenants / subscriptions, so I'd like to be able to use the result to browse and manage resources there.

This is something very close to what I would believe Azure Data Studio does: you can enter some Azure creds, and your resources will appear in the app.

I'm trying to understand the best approach for this.  There seem to be a billion sites out there when you talk about Azure AD app registrations, but I haven't found a fruitful specific search query yet.  I know I can register an app, get a client ID and client secret.  I know I can set it to be usable by organisational accounts in the current tenant, or all tenants.

I can add the "Azure Service Management (delegated permissions : user_impersonation)" permission to my API permissions section for the app, but what's next?

If I use `Microsoft.Identity.Client` (as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon), I run into some questions:

1. `AcquireTokenForClientAsync` doesn't prompt the user - I guess because it's getting a token for the app to act with its own permissions?
2. `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync` wants a JWT.. great! I'll pass the one I got from `AcquireTokenForClientAsync`!  Nope, `AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS500137: The token issuer doesn't match the api version: A version 1 token cannot be used with the v2 endpoint`.
3. I don't know what scope I want.  `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` is apparently invalid.. `https://management.azure.com/.default` works, but is that right? It's a guess, combo of the former and a `.default` suffix I found for Graph API scopes online.  Any docs on this?
4. I ultimately get a JWT and tenant ID back.  I can't find a way to use a JWT with the Fluent management APIs.. and my account (for instance) is associated with 3 tenants or 5 different tenants / directories - so how do I choose?

That's just what I've tried, the appropriate route might be a different one.  In summary: I want a .NET Core Console app to request user credentials, and then get access to the Azure resources they have access to, in order to perform some resource management.

Answer (score 1):

> AcquireTokenForClientAsync doesn't prompt the user - I guess because it's getting a token for the app to act with its own permissions?

You are using the  [OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) to access web-hosted resources by using the identity of an application. This type of grant commonly is used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background, without immediate interaction with a user .

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS500137: The token issuer doesn't match the api version: A version 1 token cannot be used with the v2 endpoint.

Azure AD provide two service : Azure AD V1.0 and Azure AD V2.0 . Please refer to [Comparing the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint with the v1.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison) . You can't use v1 token to acquire v2's token in a [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) .

> AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync wants a JWT.. great! I'll pass the one I got from AcquireTokenForClientAsync

AS pointed above , That function is used to acquire an access token for this application (usually a Web API) from the authority configured in the application, in order to access another downstream protected Web API on behalf of a user using the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow. So you can't use app token which acquire using [Client Credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) .

> https://management.azure.com/.default works, but is that right? It's a guess, combo of the former and a .default suffix I found for Graph API scopes online. Any docs on this?

You are using the [Azure Active Directory v2.0 and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison) , when sending  a POST request to the /token v2.0 endpoint ,the scope should be :

> > The value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the resource identifier (Application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix. For the Microsoft Graph example, the value is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. This value informs the v2.0 endpoint that of all the direct application permissions you have configured for your app, it should issue a token for the ones associated with the resource you want to use.

Please check the `Get a token`section in above document .

> > I ultimately get a JWT and tenant ID back. I can't find a way to use a JWT with the Fluent management APIs..

AFAIK , currently Azure AD V2.0 apps can use:

- Its own API
- Microsoft Outlook APIs
- Microsoft Graph API

Azure AD V2.0 currently doesn't support Azure management APIs .

So you problem is you need to allows work and school accounts from Azure AD and personal Microsoft accounts (MSA) which works with Azure AD V2.0 , but you can't use Azure management APIs . You can use Azure management APIs in Azure AD V1.0 but it allows only work and school accounts to sign in to your application , unless you invite Microsoft accounts as guest user in Azure AD V1.0 ,but you need to configure to point to the tenant-specific endpoint :`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}).` during authentication if you want to login with MSA in v1.0 apps.

---

Update:

You can use [Code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) and azure ad v1.0 endpoint , user will be redirect to AAD's login page and enter their credential. [Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) is code sample for .net Core .

With Azure AD V1.0 endpoint ,  requests are sent to an endpoint that multiplexes across all Azure AD tenants: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common . When Azure AD receives a request on the /common endpoint, it signs the user in and, as a consequence, discovers which tenant the user is from. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) . But in this scenerio ,you can only use work and school accounts(AAD) account to login .

The code sample in your link is using Azure Service Principal for Authentication , no interactive user login . You can use OpenID Connect Owin Middleware for authentication in .net Core applications as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) .

Comment: Thank you!  What would be the correct or standardised approach then to prompt the user then use Azure management APIs?  How would I specify the tenant ID during authentication when I don't know what it is yet?  Would you happen to know how to get any of this to work with the Fluent APIs (https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net)?  I know those are a lot of questions, sorry :)